# Prove that $f$ is linear when$\frac1{t-s}\int_s^tf(x)\,dx=\frac{f(s)+f(t)}2$ for all reals $s < t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ have a continuous second derivative. Suppose for all $s,t \in \mathbb R$ with $s<t$ we have $$\frac1{t-s}\int_s^tf(x)\,dx=\frac{f(s)+f(t)}2.$$ Show there exist $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f(x)=\alpha x+\beta$.

I think I use second fundamental theorem of calculus or I use the mean value theorem of integrals. Another thing I thought is the right hand side is the midpoint between two functions; so I think the function has to have the midpoint of the two endpoints involved.

Comment: Have you tried applying any of these ideas?

Comment: Please provide a meaningful title next time your post a question. Requesting for help isn't providing good knowledge on your question!

Comment: @robjohn So what I have is by the FTC, for any $p$ which $s \leq p \leq t$, then  $\int_{s}^{x} f(p) dp  = f(x)$. Then, $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (t - s) \frac{f(s) + f(t)}{2}$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: This is the integral version of the well-known series result: $\frac{1}{n-m+1}\sum_{k=m}^n a_k = \frac{a_m + a_n}{2}$ when $a_k$ is an arithmetic progression (a linear function).

Comment: @stevieman The FTC should read $\int_s^x f'(p)dp=f(x)-f(s)$ or $\partial_x\int_s^x f(p)dp=f(x)$.

Comment: @robjohn I tried using FTC for both sides but I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: Your comments came after the complete answer that was given to this question. If you'd had these ideas, why not simply apply them? If you get stuck, then ask a question.

Comment: Next time: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\int_s^t fdx=(t-s)(f(t)+f(s))/2$, differentiating with respect to $t$ gives $f(t)=(f(t)+f(s))/2+(t-s)f'(t)/2$ so $f(t)-f(s)=(t-s)f'(t)$. Differentiating with respect to $s$ gives $-f'(s)=-f'(t)$, so $f'$ is constant.